# Jade shortcut for writing lists

Tags: pug

Is there a way to drop the need for `ol` and `ul` in jade lists - I want to write...

```
ol first item
li second item
li third item
```

seems like too much indenting otherwise

Currently, I am thinking I could make a filter that wraps each line with `<li>|</li>` and call the filter `:ol` so I can do...

```
:ol
  first line
  second line
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2):

Be very careful with the two points, at the beginning of a line, that Jade will interpret as another language (Stylus, markdown ... etc). The proper way to list the case is not so important.

```
ul
  li frist item
  li second item
ol
  li frist item number
  li second item number
```

This would translate into html so

```
<ul>
   <li>frist item</li>
   <li>second item</li>
</ul>
<ol>
   <li>frist item number</li>
   <li>second item number</li>
</ol>
```

really the most important thing is the tabulation to be generated either html

Comment: Please stop vandalizing your posts. Kindly let the mods know if you have a problem.