# What am I doing wrong with structuring lists in this jade document?

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I am getting this error

[image: error]

I had found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12305844/jade-shortcut-for-writing-lists) for formatting lists in jade. And have this error when I add the next section of content which has a list

```
h3 Patient Benefits
ul 
  li Chip-resistant, as it is made of solid zirconia with no porcelain overlay
  li Glazed to a smooth surface to reduce plaque accumulation
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a space after the `ul` 
 remove that and the problem should go away.

Comment: How is that even possible :( well you were right though. I did not know that could happen.

Comment: Jade is finicky when it comes to random whitespace. It was interpreting that space as text inside the `ul` element, which is illegal.

Answer (score 1):

Jade is whitespace sensitive syntax like HAML, i used to face this error due to extra spaces.

Below are the few helpful link:

[Jade Template Language Editor](http://fiddlesalad.com/jade/)

[Jade Syntax Documentation](http://naltatis.github.io/jade-syntax-docs/)

[HTML to Jade converter](http://html2jade.aaron-powell.com/)